# localStorage different keys

Tags: html, local-storage, key

I have the following:

```
localStorage.setItem("list",listoption1);
localStorage.setItem("list",listoption2);
// ...
localStorage.setItem("list",listoption10);
```

I also have:

```
localStorage.setItem("settings",settingval);
```

I want to list all list options, but when I ask for `localStorage.key(i)` I also receive the value from the settings key. Is it possible to get everyting stored in list key only?

Answer (score 0):

The [`localStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) is a key-value storage. So storing key `list` with value of `listoption1` will store the value of `listoption1`variable to the key `list`. The next method will overwrite this key with value of `listoption2`.

Fetching `list` with `localStorage.getItem('list')` will return the value of `listoption2`, so there is no way to fetch all list options because the latter will overwrite the preceding.

*Update:*

If you want to save a Hash (Dictionary, Object, ...) to your key. Then you need to encode it somehow. I would choose JSON.

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify({ listoption1: listoption1, listoption2: listoption2 }));
var options = JSON.deceode(localStorage.getItem("list"));
alert(options.listoption1);
```